# Best way to password-protect folders on IIS

Tags: authentication, iis, directory, protected

What is the best way to password-protect a folder on IIS with a single set of credentials to be shared by a group of users?

Our hosting service offers Plesk, which in turn offers a "password-protected directory" function, but some of our clients have HTTP authorization disabled, so they get an automatic 401.4 error with no prompt for credentials.

I've looked into Forms authentication but this seems cumbersome to set up for the numerous separate domains at issue.

The protected content is not super sensitive, we just don't want it easily accessible to the public.  Many of our users do not use the site frequently and we don't want to implement individual credentialing for everyone (we do have that in place for more sensitive sections) just so they can view current project reports or meeting minutes.

On sites I don't control, but am just a user, that do the same things as mine, it is a big pain to have to look up a username and password twice per year just to view a meeting agenda (yes, browser could remember but they also have a 4-month expiration and lots of us are on different devices all the time).

Is Forms authentication the way to go?  Took a several hours for me to get it set up and working, with all sorts of settings not well documented in a single place.

(I had previously asked about how to disable Basic Auth on the client side, was told more than once it's not possible - but it is, via client/browser registry keys)

Thanks.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is usually off topic here, as this is a feature not built-in. Forms authentication is still the way to go, either you teach yourself out, or hire an experienced consultant. It's just not an easy task as you ask for flexibility.

Comment: Thank you.  Didn't know that recommendations were off topic but I can see why... I guess my question should have been whether forms authentication is outdated and you did answer that... I did build a working version just wasn't sure about viability.

Comment: Forms authentication is not an obsolete method. Forms authentication enables user and password validation for Web applications that do not require Windows authentication. With forms authentication, user information is stored in an external data source, such as a Membership database, or in the configuration file for an application. Once a user is authenticated, forms authentication maintains an authentication ticket in a cookie or in the URL so that an authenticated user does not need to supply credentials with each request.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to use forms authentication. All you need to do is navigate to the folder or file you want to protect, then go to Authorization Rules. Add a deny rule for anonymous users, when users who are not logged in try to click on any file in that folder, they will be redirected to your login page. You can find a lot of guides on forms authentication in Google, you can refer to the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-CN/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/forms-based-authentication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline